Chroma DB Creatation Kernal Dead Midway
I would like to create a ChromaDB with csv in a folder. In each of the csv, each line is a document (text). I am using Gemini embedding model.
My code do run. But the kernel will die after around 100 documents.
It throws the error code as below:
[error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221225477, Reason:
The  The Chroma DB is created.  My code as below:
# Set up the embedding model
embed_model = GeminiEmbedding(
    model_name="models/embedding-001",
    api_key=os.environ["GEMINI_API_KEY"],
)
# Create a ServiceContext
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm,
    embed_model=embed_model,
    chunk_size=1000,
    chunk_overlap=200,
)

def create_chroma_db_from_csv_folder(folder_path, db_path, collection_name):
    # Initialize Chroma client
    chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=db_path)
    
    # Create or get the collection with the correct embedding function
    # chroma_collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection(
        # name=collection_name
    # )
    chroma_collection = chroma_client.create_collection(name=collection_name)

    # Create vector store
    vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)

    # Initialize text splitter
    splitter = SentenceSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)

    # Get all CSV files in the folder
    csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
    
    for csv_file in csv_files:
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, csv_file)

                
                try:
                    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    continue
                
                # Assume the text column is named 'text'. Adjust if it's named differently.
                if 'Body' not in df.columns:
                    continue
                
                # Process each row in the dataframe
                for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0], desc=f"Processing {csv_file}"):
                    doc_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Generate a unique ID for each document
                    text = row['Body']
                    
                    # Create metadata from other columns
                    metadata = row.drop('Body').to_dict()
                    
                    # Create a Document object
                    document = Document(text=text, metadata=metadata, id_=doc_id)
                    
                    # Insert the document into the index
                    VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
                        [document],
                        storage_context=storage_context,
                        service_context=service_context
                    )

    print(f"Chroma database created at {db_path}")
    print(f"Total documents in collection: {chroma_collection.count()}")

db_path = "./chroma_db"
collection_name = "csv_documents"
create_chroma_db_from_csv_folder(folder_path, db_path, collection_name)

What I did wrong that cause the kernel to die?

I encountered the same issue when working with ChromaDB. The problem is that ChromaDB has a very good implementation for the OpenAIEmbeddings. But if it comes to using local embedding models like from Gemma, Ollama, etc..., ChromaDB encounters heavy issues.
My Solution was to use other VectorDB`s like FAISS. Langchain gives a very good tutorial to get started with FAISS. Its twice the same as Chroma and works with other embedding models.

I would recommend to use either FAISS or Supabase (we use this one in projec to support both pgVector and pgSQL) or Milvus, as vectorstore for production
